Grand Total of the pandas Pivot table
I am working on a scenario where I have to find the Sub Total and Grand Total of the Picot table created in python. getting an error and requesting your feedback on the same.
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   %I     J    K
W   P   E   6   0   0   0   0   0%     0    0
W   P   F   3   0   0   0   0   0%     0    0
W   P   G   1   0   0   0   0   0%     0    0
X   P   H   23  2   2   0   0   76%    0    0
X   P   I   8   0   0   0   0   0%     0    0
X   P   J   1   0   0   0   0   0%     0    0
X   P   E   5   2   0   1   0   78%    0    0
X   P   K   36  0   0   0   0   0%     0    0
X   P   F   35  5   5   0   0   89%    1    0
X   P   G   40  9   6   2   1   22%    4    0
X   P   L   6   1   0   1   0   45%    0    0

Column A, B and C are the Index columns and I am trying to get the

Sub Total at the column A Level so Total of Value W and Total of Value X
Grand Total from D to K
How do I calculate getting the Total % value? I cannot aggr sum or any other operation as I feel it would not give me the right answer.

tbl = pd.pivot_table(
    C,
    values=['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', '% I', 'J', 'K'],
    index=['A', 'B', 'C'],
    aggfunc=[{
        'D': np.sum,
        'E': np.sum,
        'F': np.sum,
        'G': np.sum,
        'H': np.sum,
        '% I': np.sum,
        'J': np.sum,
        'K': np.sum}],
    fill_value=0,
    margins=True,
    margins_name='Total')

Expected Output
A   B   C      D    E   F   G  H  %I     J  K
W   P   E      6    0   0   0  0  0%     0  0
W   P   F      3    0   0   0  0  0%     0  0
W   P   G      1    0   0   0  0  0%     0  0
Sub Total (W)  10   0   0   0  0  Auto%  0  0
X   P   H      23   2   2   0  0  76%    0  0
X   P   I      8    0   0   0  0  0%     0  0
X   P   J      1    0   0   0  0  0%     0  0
X   P   E      5    2   0   1  0  78%    0  0
X   P   K      36   0   0   0  0  0%     0  0
X   P   F      35   5   5   0  0  89%    1  0
X   P   G      40   9   6   2  1  22%    4  0
X   P   L      6    1   0   1  0  45%    0  0
Sub Total (X)  154  19  13  4  1  Auto%  5  0
Grand Total    164  19  13  4  1  Auto%  5  0


What's the error?

What does "Auto%" mean?

I couldn't understand what type of aggr function is used while calculating the Sub Total and Total for the percentage so used a generic word as Auto.

The error is "InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

@Ishan For the percentage, we don't know what the right answer is. You need to figure that out for yourself. FWIW, there are contexts where a sum would be exactly what you need. If you want to [edit] and remove that from the question, please do. Stack Overflow questions should be about one specific problem. On that note, if you want help with the error, you need to include it in the question and provide a [mre]. See also How to make good reproducible pandas examples. For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Assuming I understood your question correctly, you have to calculate the subtotals and grand total manually for the specific column. Since I don't know which aggregated function you want, I assumed that it was the mean, but you can change that easily. Just play around with the code to achieve what you want. So, something like this could do the job:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
    'A': ['W', 'W', 'W', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X'],
    'B': ['P'] * 11,
    'C': ['E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'E', 'K', 'F', 'G', 'L'],
    'D': [6, 3, 1, 23, 8, 1, 5, 36, 35, 40, 6],
    'E': [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 5, 9, 1],
    'F': [0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 0],
    'G': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
    'H': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    '% I': ['0%', '0%', '0%', '76%', '0%', '0%', '78%', '0%', '89%', '22%', '45%'],
    'J': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 4, 0],
    'K': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(
    df,
    values=['D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K'],
    index=['A', 'B', 'C'],
    aggfunc=np.sum,
    fill_value=0,
    margins=True,
    margins_name='Total'
)

df['% I'] = df['% I'].str.rstrip('%').astype(float)
pivot_table['% I'] = df.groupby(['A', 'B', 'C'])['% I'].mean()

subtotals = pivot_table.groupby(level=0).sum()
subtotals['% I'] = df.groupby('A')['% I'].mean()
grand_total = pivot_table.sum()
grand_total['% I'] = df['% I'].mean()

subtotals = subtotals.rename(index=lambda x: f'Sub Total ({x})')
pivot_table = pd.concat([pivot_table, subtotals])
pivot_table.loc['Grand Total'] = grand_total

pivot_table = pivot_table.reset_index()

The result from the code is:

